# oracle sqlldr -> undefined symbol: sldext

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

1. installed `oracle_client`

   - `oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`
   - `oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`
   - `oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm`
2. copy `sqlldr` file to `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin`
3. copy `rdbms`,`nls` folder to  `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/`
4. settings `.bash_profile`

   ```
   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
   export NLS_LANG=KOREAN_KOREA.KO16KSC5601
   export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
   export ORA_NLS10=$ORACLE_HOME/nls/data
   export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

but, executed `ldd -r sqlldr` follow next line

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff03fff000)
        libclntsh.so.11.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0x00007f6f036bb000)
        libnnz11.so => /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libnnz11.so (0x00007f6f032ed000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000037fae00000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000037fa600000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000037fb600000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00000037fce00000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000037faa00000)
        libaio.so.1 => /lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f6f030e0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000037fa200000)
undefined symbol: sldext        (./sqlldr)
undefined symbol: sldextf       (./sqlldr)
```

.bash_profile

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export ORA_NLS10=$ORACLE_HOME/nls/data
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

How to remove `undefined symbol`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is at the following library:

`/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1`

Change this library to an older version and it will work.
We saw that the 11.2.0.4 version of the library is throwing this error while the 11.2.0.3 version just works.

Comment: I'd like to try that but where can 11.2.0.3 be found now?

Comment: Here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html